# obtener datos actualizados del store antes de renderizar los componentes

Tags: redux, react-redux, electron

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con electronjs y estoy teniendo un problema al crear los loader del componente CreateBrowserRouter

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <DashboardPage />,
    loader: async () => {
    },
  },
  {
    path: "signin",
    element: <SigninPage />,
    loader: async () => {
    }
  }
]);
```

en el loader del signin intente con lo siguiente:

```
 const { auth } = store.getState()
  if(!auth.loading && auth.access) return redirect("/")
  else return null
```

pero el renderizado no se condiciona con los datos actualizados, estoy trayendo datos desde el proceso main, en el punto de entrada de react: app.tsx, estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
window.api.receive("init-data", value => {
  store.dispatch(handleTokenAuth(value))
})
```

pero el loader solo ve los datos anteriores a la escucha del window.api.receive.

en resumen, la aplicacion recibe datos del proceso main para determinar si hay una sesion o no, la recibo y la establezco en el store de redux, en base a esa sesion se renderiza el dashboard o el signin.